# EF core 2.14 Map few same type objects to a single table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

Let's say we want to save a payment to db

```
Public class Payment{

   protected Payment()
   {
   }

   Public string Id{get;set}
   Public Money Fee {get; set;}
   Public Money Amount {get; set;}
}

Public class Money{
   public decimal Amount{get; set;}
   public string Description{get;set} 
}
```

Now the error I get in mapping is :

Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Payment.Amount' of type 'Money'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

```
 public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Payment> builder)
        {
           //Do some smart mapping here, rename for Fee money object only Amount to fee & ignore description
            builder.OwnsOne(
               a => a.Fee
            );
        }
```

everything works fine if I only have a single Money object in Payment class

Comment: What's the issue? If you want `Money` to be owned entity type, make sure to map it as owned in every place you use it, e.g. `builder.OwnsOne(p => p.Amount);` additionally to `builder.OwnsOne(p => p.Fee)`. Or mark the `Money` class with  `[Owned]` attribute.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Thank you!!!